# characteristics graph

Tags: jfet, fet

[image]

I'm currently learning about Field Effect Transistors in my college class. And I'm having trouble understanding how to properly read characteristics curve graphs. I'm sure it's relatively simple, but when we get asked questions like determine I<sub>D</sub> when V<sub>GS</sub> is -5 or -1.2 how would I go about determining the results?

I've searched my book and the web and I can't seem to find the formula. The examples in the book jump right to the answer without showing the method of determining the result.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of IDSS ? If yes - your example question "determine IDSS when VGS=-5V" makes no sense at all. At the top of the diagram, the IDSS value is given (it is the current IDS for VGS=0).

Comment: @LvW that 8uA number is a bit suspect. 8mA.

Comment: Oh yes - I think so. I guess, should be 8mA (see the vertical axis in mA)..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out LvW, I've corrected the question to what I was actually asking. I'm looking to understand how to determine values for Id. The big picture is, I'm trying to understand what the formulas are regarding these three elements ID, VGS and VDS as shown by characteristic graphs.

Comment: @Stampede: ID is simply a function of the applied VGS voltage. A value of VGS=-1V gives you a current of ID=4.5 mA. This assumes, of course, that the voltage VDS exceeds app. 6 Volts (see diagram). That means the voltage drop at the drain resistor ID*RD must allow this voltage VDS. Design Example: Vsupply=20V, ID=4.5mA, ID*RD=4.5mA*2kOhms=9V, VDS=20-9=11V.

Answer (score 1):

Stampede - of course, one could ask "what is the current ID for VGS=... and VDS=..." , however, that is a simple task.

For my opinion, much more important is the question: What does such a diagram tells us about the main properties of the device?

**Here is my answer**: As you can see, there is a current ID through the drain-source path which is nearly constant. That means: Nearly independent on the VOLTAGE between D and S. What is this? This is a typical characteristic of a (constant) CURRENT SOURCE. And more than that, this current ID depends on (can be controlled by) the voltage VGS. Hence, we have a **CONTROLLED CURRENT SOURCE**.

And exactly this is the property of the FET which is exploited in its application for a voltage amplifier: When the FET output current ID goes to a load resistor RD (between D and the supply voltage) we have a voltage drop which can be made much larger than the input voltage VGS (using a corresponding large resistor RD).

The shown curves are a bit idealized because - in reality - they have a slight positive slope which indicates that the current source has an internal source resistance other than infinite (ideal). In this case, the slope is the inverse of the resistance rds (1/rds, small letters because it is a differential resistance).

Comment: That definitely helps explain the players on the field here. Basically, what effect the graph is trying to explain.  My next question is though, the elements of IDSS, VGS and VDS relate and effect one another. What would be the mathematical formula to represent their interaction in the JFET, as displayed by these characteristic graphs.   For example if we needed find the values of VGS and IDSS at a particular VDS point?

Comment: @Stamp: That's just reading the graph and is hardly worth explaining here.